# java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Invalid type oid?

Tags: java, sql

I'm getting this error at this line:

```
Object[] results = (Object[])stmt.getArray(1).getArray();
```

Not sure what it means...

I can show the sql also...can someone explain what this error means...I also have that stac trace if needed

```
public List<SimilarItemSearchCollectBean> getSimilarItemSearchCollect(
        PagerTagHelper pagerHelper,
        String codes,
        String params[] )
            throws Exception
                {

    if( params.length != codes.length() ) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Number of codes does not match number of parameters: (" +
                codes.length() + " != " + params.length + ")."
                );

            int i = 0;
            String temp = null;
            List<SimilarItemSearchCollectBean> collected = null;
            String funCall = "{ call ? := " + PKG_PREFIX
            + "summarize_item_search_data( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) }";

            OracleCallableStatement stmt = null;

            try
            {
                java.util.Map<String,Class<?>> map = connection.getTypeMap();
                map.put( schemaProvider.getSystemSchemaName()+".SIMILAR_ITEM_SEARCH_ROLLUP", SimilarItemSearchCollectBean.class );

                stmt = (OracleCallableStatement)connection.prepareCall( funCall );

                stmt.registerOutParameter(
                1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, schemaProvider.getSystemSchemaName()+".BEAN_LIST" );

                stmt.setInt( 2, pagerHelper.getStartIndex() );
                stmt.setInt( 3, pagerHelper.getEndIndex() );
                stmt.setObject( 4, DAOUtil.getARRAY( DAOUtil.ArrayTypes.CHAR_TAB, pagerHelper.getPropertyNames() ));
                stmt.setObject( 5, DAOUtil.getARRAY( DAOUtil.ArrayTypes.CHAR_TAB, pagerHelper.getSortOrders() ));

                /* Initialize all the parameters to null.
                 * We will re set them individually in the switch if
                 * there is an actual value.
                 */

                stmt.setString( 6, null  );     // value1
                stmt.setString( 7, null  );     // value2
                stmt.setNull( 8, OracleTypes.NUMBER );      // sac
                stmt.setNull( 9, OracleTypes.NUMBER );     // job type id
                stmt.setNull( 10, OracleTypes.NUMBER );  // standard unit price

                // Still need to decide how searching will occur for year ranges
                for( i=0; i<codes.length(); i++ )
                {
                    if ( params[i] != null )
                    {
                        switch( codes.charAt(i) )
                        {
                        case '0':   // VALUE1
                            temp = params[i].replace( '*', '%' );
                            temp = temp.replaceAll("%+", "%");
                            stmt.setString( 6, temp );
                            break;
                        case '1':   // VALUE2
                            stmt.setString( 7, params[i] );
                            break;
                        case '2':   // VALUE3
                            stmt.setInt( 8, Integer.parseInt(params[i]) );
                            break;
                        case '3':   // JOB TYPE ID
                            stmt.setLong( 9, Long.parseLong( params[i] ) );
                            break;
                        case '4':   // VALUE4
                            stmt.setLong( 10, Long.parseLong(params[i]));
                            break;


                        default:

                        } // end switch
                    } // if not null
                } // end for

                stmt.execute();

                // ERROR  HERE:
                Object[] results = (Object[])stmt.getArray(1).getArray();


                collected = new ArrayList<SimilarItemSearchCollectBean>();
                for( i=0; i<results.length; i++ )
                    collected.add( (SimilarItemSearchCollectBean)results[i] );

            } // end try
            finally { close( stmt ); }
            return collected;
        } // end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with `OracleCallableStatement`, but shouldn't that be

```
Object[] results = (Object[])(stmt.getARRAY(1).getArray());
```

[`oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement#getARRAY(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#getARRAY_int_) is `OracleCallableStatement`-specific, `getArray()` seems to be inherited from [`java.sql.CallableStatement#getArray(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#getArray%28int%29).

Already said i'm not familiar with this, but `getARRAY` seems to fit better with the `OracleTypes.ARRAY` type you registered as out parameter.